# Converting a material-ui class to a function

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux, react-router, material-ui

I am learning material-ui, and most of the code available uses classes (which I'm more familiar with since object-oriented background).  But the new paradigm is supposedly to use functions i/o classes because of the introduction of hooks.

I see all kinds of questions about converting functions to classes but can't find ONE example of converting a class to a function.

I'm trying to convert this code to a function:

```
class MouseTracker extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleMouseMove = this.handleMouseMove.bind(this);
    this.state = { x: 0, y: 0 };
  }

  handleMouseMove(event) {
    this.setState({
      x: event.clientX,
      y: event.clientY
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div style={{ height: '100vh' }} onMouseMove={this.handleMouseMove}>
        <h1>Move the mouse around!</h1>
        <p>The current mouse position is ({this.state.x}, {this.state.y})</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I have zero clue how to deal with the super(props) statement.  Here's my attempt that doesn't work.

```
function MouseTracker(props) = {
{
    super(props);
    this.handleMouseMove = this.handleMouseMove.bind(this);
    this.state = { x: 0, y: 0 };
  }

  handleMouseMove(event) {
    this.setState({
      x: event.clientX,
      y: event.clientY
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div style={{ height: '100vh' }} onMouseMove={this.handleMouseMove}>
        <h1>Move the mouse around!</h1>
        <p>The current mouse position is ({this.state.x}, {this.state.y})</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default MouseTracker
```

Thanks so much for any help!

Comment: Hope this will be helped you too. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64058857/how-to-convert-the-react-function-into-class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can search for online material based on "React Functional Components" to find out how to convert classes to functions. These components are written as if they are javascript functions and uses React hooks to handle states and other kinds of things

The "super(props)" is a React constructor class syntax. So it's not needed when you write functional components

Also, note the difference between es6 syntax and js, function MouseTracker(props) = {..} is invalid.

Here's a working example based on the mouse tracker: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-functional-component-demo-ytbrn?file=/demo.js

Here's some examples from ReactJs' documentation, and its hooks pattern:

- https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html
- https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html

Comment: Thanks so much.  Sure I found TONS of tutorials discussing converting classes to functions, but nothing on superprops converting to function.  Thanks for the help!