# How to convert the react function into class?

Tags: reactjs, function, class

I'm used the material-UI to develop the react.js frontend. But when I'm gonna develop it furthermore(to implement the crud operations), it's hard to code, since every tutorial coded by using **class**, not a **function**. So, I tried to convert the code into the class. But I failed to do that properly.

So I just ask you guys to help me to convert the below code into the class. I would like to appreciate your kindness. Thank you.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDom from 'react-dom';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import { Container, Row, Col, Form } from "react-bootstrap";
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import { makeStyles, withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    root: {
        '& > *': {
            margin: theme.spacing(1),
            width: '25ch',
        },
    },
    button: {
        marginRight: theme.spacing(1),
    },
}));

export default function Step2(props) {

    const classes = useStyles();

    return (
        <Container style={{marginRight: 700}}>
            <Row
                style={{ marginTop: "30px" }}
                className="h-100 justify-content-center align-items-center"
            >
                <Col md={{ span: 6 }} className="text-center my-auto">
                    <h3 style={{ marginBottom: "1rem" }}>New Vehicle Details</h3>
                    <Form>
                        <form className={classes.root} noValidate autoComplete="off">
                            <TextField id="standard-basic" label="Vehicle No." required/>
                        </form>
                        <form className={classes.root} noValidate autoComplete="off">
                            <TextField id="standard-basic" label="Registered Year." required/>
                        </form>
                        <form className={classes.root} noValidate autoComplete="off">
                            <TextField id="standard-basic" label="Capacity" required/>
                        </form>
                        <form className={classes.root} noValidate autoComplete="off">
                            <TextField id="standard-basic" label="Type" required/>
                        </form>
                        <Button
                            variant="contained"
                            color="primary"
                            //onClick={handleNext}
                            className={classes.button}
                        >
                            Add
                        </Button>
                        <Button
                            variant="contained"
                            color="secondry"
                            // onClick={handleNext}
                            className={classes.button}
                        >
                            Cancel
                        </Button>
                    </Form>
                </Col>
            </Row>
        </Container>
    );
}
```

Comment: Turn `function Step2(props) { ... }` into `class Step2 extends React.Component { function render() { ... } }`. In function body use `this.props` instead of `props`.

Comment: I just tried. But there is an error.

Comment: Ah.. fine. It was a typo error. Thank you.

Comment: @RomanHocke If I want to add a constructor, does it should be before the render()?

Comment: So long as you understand the react component lifecycle it should be trivial to mentally convert `componentDidMount`, `componentDidUpdate` and `componentWillUnmount` to a `useEffect` react hook. Once proficient with functional components you likely won't want to use/create class-based components. IMO going functional -> class-based is backwards.

Answer (score 2):

you are now getting props in parameters of this function just change the function to class.

```
export default class Step2 extends React.Component {
}
```

and use props like `this.props` instead of `props`

Comment: I tried this one as well as. But the problem is the styles in before the function.

Comment: import `withStyles` and replace makeStyles with withStyles and then replace that with const classes = useStyle; like this

`const useStyles = withStyles((theme) => ({})`
`const classes = useStyles;`

Comment: That `const classes = useStyles;` should be inside of the `render(){...}` right.!?

Comment: yup that should be above return and inside render function.

Comment: also one thing please accept the answer as correct if you found it helpful.